# Find highest weight of dual representation of $\mathfrak{sl}(3,\mathbb{C})$

Tags: representation-theory, lie-groups, lie-algebras

I’m trying to approach the highest weight of the dual representation $(\pi^*,V^*)$ of a given irreducible representation $(\pi,V)$ of $\mathfrak{sl}(3,\mathbb{C})$, whose highest weight is supposed to be $(m_1,m_2)$. The partial order defined on weights is given by $$\mu_1\ge\mu_2  \iff \mu_1-\mu_2=a\alpha_1+b\alpha_2 \\a\ge 0 \\b\ge 0$$ where $\alpha_1=(-1,2),\alpha_2=(2,-1)$ are positive simple roots of $\mathfrak{sl}(3,\mathbb{C})$. The notes I read claims that $(m_2,m_1)$ will be the highest weight of $(\pi^*,V^*)$. The fact I realized is that weights of $(\pi^*,V^*)$ are negatives of $(\pi,V)$, so I tried to prove the claim by direct computation. If we let $(n_1,n_2)$ be a weight of $(\pi,V)$ lower than $(m_1,m_2)$, such that $$(m_1,m_2)-(n_1,n_2)=a_0\alpha_1+b_0\alpha_2$$
then $(-n_1,-n_2)$ will be a weight of $(\pi^*,V^*)$, so if I can prove $(m_2,m_1)\ge(-n_1,-n_2)$, then I’m done. But the computation seems not clear why this is true. $$(m_2,m_1)+(n_1,n_2)=(m_1+m_2,m_1+m_2)-(m_1-n_1,m_2-n_2)\\=(m_1+m_2)(\alpha_1+\alpha_2)-a_0\alpha_1-b_0\alpha_2\\=(m_1+m_2-a_0)\alpha_1+(m_1+m_2-b_0)\alpha_2$$
So to finish the prove, I need to show
$$m_1+m_2\ge a_0\\m_1+m_2\ge b_0$$
But I have no idea why this is true,any helps?

**Aside**: I know there are some powerful general results to solve this problem, but I’m quite new in the weight theory of representation, so I really want to prove this by just using definitions.

Comment: Have you looked at small examples, like the irrep with highest weight $(1,0)$?

Comment: Not really, will it be helpful? If so, I will check it. @TorstenSchoeneberg

Answer (score 1):

You should use the fact that the set of weights is stable under the action of the Weyl group.

The two simple reflections are $s_1,s_2$. $s_1$ acts on a weight by $s_1(n_1,n_2)=(-n_1,n_1+n_2)$.
You can check that the longest element $w_0=s_1s_2s_1$ acts by $w_0(n_1,n_2)=(-n_2,-n_1)$.

From this you get that $(n_1,n_2)$ is a weight of $V$ if and only if $(n_2,n_1)$ is a weight of $V^*$.